# fetch_array() - cannot add multiple array fields to new array

Tags: php, arrays, json, mysqli, fetch

I am trying to return a json from a MySQL query to use it with xCode but I cannot get an array of several objects with multiple fields. I have read the documentation on php.net and over here, but I still can't get it.

1) Let's say I have a MySQL table with 3 rows (for example 3 people). Each row contains 3 fields (lastname, firstname, dateOfBirth):

```
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql) // where $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_syncList"

$resultArray = array();

while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    $resultArray[] = $row["lastname"];
}
echo json_encode($resultArray); // --> return "["Lastname1", "Lastname2"...] - that's okay, I understand I return the value of the key "lastname"
```

I don't know how to get an array with the entire rows (all the fields at once), like:

```
[["Firstname1", "Lastname1", "dateOfBirth1"], ["Firstname2", "Lastname2", "dateOfBirth2"],...]
```

I tried to replace

```
$resultArray[] = $row["lastname"];
```

with:

```
$resultArray[] = $row;
```

but it just gives the world...

```
"array"
```

...with no content. Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `$resultArray[] = $row;` is correct.  You can't echo `$row` but it will give the json you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the array is properly populated to begin with? `print_r($resultArray)` and see what you have there with `= $row` (which is correct).